# Mocking JBoss get installed bean call

Tags: java, testing, easymock

I am writing some unit tests for a class that had a call to `JBossWebMicrocontainerBeanLocator                    .getInstalledBean("name")`. I want to be able to Mock the returned object using EasyMock, I'm not very familiar with its technicalities though.

My problem is that the constructor does not take the bean name as an argument, and the call to  JBoss is in a private method. I can currently see two options available to me:

1. Make a protected constructor that has the necessary arguments
2. change the visibility of the method to protected

Both of these options are undesirable as they involve changes to the code purely for testing, is there another option? This code doesn't currently use an Injection framework but this could be another area to explore.

Comment: If your tests are telling you to change your code, that's a *good* thing.

Comment: Because tests expose bad design in your code. If it's hard to test, it's telling you that your design is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, then you'll need to mock the JBossWebMicrocontainerBeanLocator's getInstalledBean method, and then in the mocked return you'll return a mocked bean Object like the example:

```
JBossWebMicrocontainerBeanLocator locatorMock EasyMock.createMock(JBossWebMicrocontainerBeanLocator.class);
EasyMock.expect(locatorMock.getInstalledBean("name")).andReturn(createBeanMock()); //where createBeanMock() returns mocked bean
EasyMock.replay(locatorMock);
```

please note that you can let the mock change the parameter "name" with anyString() which will satisfy any string passed.

I hope that helps :)